# First Element must contain the local name, Envelope , but found html error

Tags: marketing-cloud

I use RetrieveRequest (Java app) to load Data Extension records. There are more than 2500 records. First request finishes ok but second one with using "ContinueRequest" param fails with "First Element must contain the local name, Envelope , but found html" exception

Request ID is:

```
<par:ContinueRequest>4c2c5ebf-51b7-42d1-8e14-1c1fa39f543c</par:ContinueRequest>
```

What am I doing wrong with request?

Stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPProcessingException: First Element must contain the local name, Envelope , but found html
at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.constructNode(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:299)
at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.createOMElement(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:246)
at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.createNextOMElement(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:228)
at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:249)
at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.getSOAPEnvelope(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:198)
at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:154)
at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:140)
at org.apache.axis2.builder.BuilderUtil.getSOAPBuilder(BuilderUtil.java:686)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createDocumentElement(TransportUtils.java:197)
```

Comment: Please provide the code used to generate that error.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use a sniffing tool to find out what is actually getting passed through in the response? Something like [tcpmon](http://ws.apache.org/tcpmon/) or [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)?

It could be the case that your ContinueRequest is referencing something incorrectly.

Comment: Now it is not reproducible. But was reproducible for 2 days. ExactTarget can investigate it by using request id 4c2c5ebf-51b7-42d1-8e14-1c1fa39f543c in their logs. If it is reproducible again I'll add info from Fiddler. Thank you

Comment: Glad it's working.  Let us know if it shows up again for sure.